# For $f(x,y) = \sqrt{16-4x^2 - y^2}$, why is $-4$ not in the range of $f$?

Tags: calculus

[image]

When taking the square root of a function of a number, you want the inside of the root to be $≥ 0$ ... so in this example, $16-4x^2-y^2  ≥ 0$. Moving constants to one side and dividing by $16$ gives
$$
\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{16} \le 1
$$
If you plug in $0$ for $-4x^2 -y^2$ you get $z = f(x,y) =4$ and plugging in $16$ you get $z = f(x,y)= 0$. Thus range for $z$ is $[0,4]$.

How come in this problem, they are not considering $z = -4$ instead of $4$? Is it a convention thing? I know this probably boils down to what the definition of what a general function is, which is for the most basic $2$ dimensional function, for every unique $x$ there is only one $y$. I would appreciate it if I could get some clarification on this.

Comment: "*they are not considering $z=−4$*" You don't explain why the thought even crossed your mind that $z=-4$ could be considered. Without that, it's harder to guess where your confusion lies.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I forgot the basic fact that the definition of a square root “function” doesn’t include both + and -.

Comment: The square root function $y = \sqrt{x}$ only takes non-negative values, by definition. The solution set to the equation $y^2 = x$ is *not* $y = \sqrt{x}$ but $y = \pm \sqrt{x}$, which is not a (single-valued) function. That's an important distinction to keep in mind, here and in all cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is for the same reason that $\sqrt{4} \ne -2$. By definition, the square root function only yields nonnegative numbers. Hence, $z$ is never negative, since $f(x,y)$ is defined as a  square root of a quantity.

Comment: I see…so the reason why equations of circles can allow 2 outputs for one input is because they are not actual “functions”?

Comment: That has nothing to do with my answer, but that said - it depends on context. Interpreted as a function $y$ of one variable $x$ in Cartesian coordinates, a circle cannot be written as a function of $x$, i.e. you cannot solve for $y$ in $x^2+y^2=1$ and arrive at a function of $y$ that isn't in some way really just two or more functions. In polar coordinates, sure, a circle is a function, e.g. $r = \sin \theta$, but then items like the vertical line test will fail (since they presuppose Cartesian coordinates).

Comment: In three-dimensional space (where $z$ is a function of $x,y$), it is trivial to have a circle as a function within a restricted sense. As an equally trivial example, define $D$ to be the unit circle in the $x,y$ plane, and define the function with graph in $3D$ space by $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y) = 0$. Then the graph is trivially a circle.

Comment: @thuang If this answer answers your question, please remember to accept it by clicking the check mark.